# powerquery : combining two tables for each data

Tags: excel, merge, powerquery

i have two tables

one includes dates (table1)

```
Date
11/10/2019
11/17/2019
```

the other one has names (table2)

```
Name Surname
xxxxxx
yyyyyy
```

i want to combine the second table for each data in the table1

result should be

```
Name Surname      Date
xxxxxx           11/10/2019
yyyyyy           11/10/2019
xxxxxx           11/17/2019
yyyyyy           11/17/2019
```

i am sure it is very for you guys,

thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy:

```
= Table.Join(table2,{},table1,{})
```

Comment: `spasibo eshe raz` )))

Comment: ne za chto eshchyo raz)